# .net Shared Project how to access and use static files?

Tags: javascript, .net, shared-project

I added a shared project in my solution, I want to add partial views and static resources (css, images, JavaScript). How do I access them, what is the path for them?

```
this is my structure:
SharedProject
/views/viewName.cshtml
/js/javascriptFile.js
```

In my project how do I reference them?

In a bundle `config` for example, what is the correct path?

I tried reference them directly `/js/javascriptFile.js` and using the project root namespace `/SharedProject/js/javascriptFile.js`. But, none of this work.